# how to fix : Missing &quot;use strict&quot; statement

Tags: angularjs

JSHint: Missing "use strict" statement. (E007)
I have this error in my error part and I don't know how to fix and I don't even know what does it mean.

Comment: You just have to add `"use strict";` to the beginning of your JavaScript file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)